# searching an item in a multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, search, multidimensional-array, find

i have this multidimensional array in python.

```
hello = [(['b', 'y', 'e'], 3), (['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], 5), (['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], 5)]
```

and I wanted to find the index of number 3, I tried using hello.index(3) but won't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> [x[0] for x in hello if x[1] == 3][0]
['b', 'y', 'e']
```

if you need index of item, try

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(hello) if x[1] == 3][0]
0
```

for multiple results just remove `[0]` at the end:

```
>>> hello.append((list("spam"), 3))
>>> hello
[(['b', 'y', 'e'], 3), (['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], 5), (['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], 5), (['s', 'p', 'a', 'm'], 3)]
>>> [x[0] for x in hello if x[1] == 3]
[['b', 'y', 'e'], ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']]
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(hello) if x[1] == 3]
[0, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: What about multiple result?

Comment: @AdemÖztaş: `index()` only finds the first occurrence so this solution does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
>>> [ i for i in hello if i[1] == 3 ]
[(['b', 'y', 'e'], 3)]
```